# How to submit a form from custom phtml in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, controllers, model, forms

I have created a custom module and I have a custom phtml file with a form.

I have also created a new table for this module.

What I want to do is to insert the value of form in the DB But I actually don't know the flow for that.

What I mean is how can I send my form to a controller and then access the model to make operations?

Can anyone help my with an example how to do that?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create controller first and add it on form action.

Then in controller you can get form values by :

`$name = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue("name"); // here i have taken example for name field`

Then same way you need to create model and resource model to store data in your custom table.

**Refer this link for more details** -  http://clever-code.com/how-to-save-form-data-to-the-custom-table-in-magento-2/

Comment: and then? if i want to insert those values in my custom tables how can i make this connection between controller and model?

Comment: Yes refer below link it will give exact idea how you need to manage db connection with your custom module , you need to create model , resource model and its collection , in collection file you need to mention db name and  its id

Comment: thank you for the answer, now i can take my variables into my controller, but in your link i can't find nothing how  the model and resource model should look like.

Comment: @AlinLupoiu , for model and resource model setup use this link - https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/how-to-create-crud-model-magento-2.html

Comment: @AlinLupoiu you can also refer this one - https://jutesenthil.wordpress.com/2016/04/06/how-to-insert-data-into-custom-table-in-magento2-part3/

Answer (score 3):

In custom phtml, form action you have to give your controller url.

**Below is the example :**

```
<form name="form_sample" id="form_sample" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl() . 'sample/index/save'; ?>" method="post">
```

In controller, you can get the value and save into the db.

Example:

```
//Getting the form values

$data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

//Save into db

$model = $this->obectManager->create('vendor/modulename/model/sample');
$model->setData($data);
$model->save();
```